# How to pass session object when navigate url is used

Tags: asp.net

I'm using hyperlink navigateurl , It opens a popup (which is a aspx page) this popup loads based on the data from the session object. How can I pass the session object in the navigateurl. Can any one advise me.

Answer (score 0):

The first think you need to understand is that navigateUrl doesn't cause postback. You cannot control with server side code after user clicks the link.
 I think the only way we can do this is to construct the url at runtime with the session value concatenated with the url as QueryString. Look at this example: Suppose you have a control with the id="HyperLink1". You can place it in Page_Load event

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "~/popup.aspx?val=" + Session["ur_value"];
```

then in the popup.aspx page extract the QueryString from the url in the Page_Load event

```
string xx=Request.QueryString("val");//if the value was string
```

But why do you want to pass the session value with the navigateUrl anyway?
You can access the session values in your popup aspx page directly with the session object.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the detailed answer and suggestion. I'm working on already developed  page which is used in some others forms too. I want to use  the same page but do not want to see few other controls existing on that page.

Comment: I didn't get your point yet.  May be you can explain more so that others also may tell us what to do. Thank you